# Make sure spring component is stateless

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, multithreading

We faced a multi-threading problem when a developer introduced mutability to a Spring Component. Something like this:

```
@Component //singleton
public class MyComponent {
...
private String intermediateResults;
public String businessMethod() {
 ... fills in intermediateResults;
}

public String thisGetterShouldNotBeHere() {
    return intermediateResults;
 }
}
```

which led to bug with multithreading - the field intermediateResults has been accessed from different threads.

Is there are a way to prevent adding state to a Spring Singleton e.g. by some kind of static analyzer?
SonarQube plugins? Eclipse plugins?
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777849/proper-usage-of-synchronized-singleton

Comment: Just one question: Isn't it the `businessMethod()` making the class mutable, instead of the Getter?

Comment: For sure businessMethod made it mutable.

Comment: The problem is not how to fix it - it's easy, just remove mutability. The problem is how to know that kind of mutability has been introduced

Comment: Why don't you train the Developers? Probably buy them some books on Concurrent Application Development.

Comment: @shazin you're right, but in case of delegation or outsourcing we should be also able to control the quality in more or less automated way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MutabilityDetector](https://github.com/MutabilityDetector/MutabilityDetector) seems able to do exactly what you need:

> Mutability Detector is designed to analyse Java classes and report on whether instances of a given class are immutable. It can be used:
>
> - In a unit test, with an assertion like assertImmutable(MyClass.class). Is your class actually immutable? What about after that change you just made?
> - As a FindBugs plugin. Those classes you annotated with @Immutable, are they actually?
>     At runtime. Does your API require being given immutable objects?
>     From the command line. Do you want to quickly run Mutability Detector over an entire code base?

I would anyway advise to add a clear contract stating that the class is supposed to be immutable either via `javadoc` or via  `@Immutable` annotation on the class itself, to allow (sensible) developers to maintain the class requisites. (In case Mutability Detector fails to detect specific types of immutability eg: [Are String, Date really immutable?](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/are-string-method-date-immutable.html))

Comment: Seems a nice tool. Will give it a try

Comment: @Andres It is indeed, try to verify a class that accept a collection from constructor and sets its final state with Collection.unmodifiableCollection(...). You will be surprised from the result :)

Comment: That's a great tool, thank you very much, @snovelli!

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your own rules with any static analyzer (Like FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle) to check that your class:

- Only allows final properties
- Extends a given class
- Is final
- Uses constructor dependency injection

However, as far as I know, there's no tool specifically configured out of the box for that.

Alternatively you could create an `@Immutable` annotation and implement the checks there.

Comment: Many Spring applications use dependency injection through a setter. In that case, `final` is not an option. Not sure about autowiring final fields - do you have any experience with that?

Comment: You'll have to use constructor dependency injection if you want to ensure immutability

Comment: Use constructor dependency injection. Not only solves this case but has several advantages. See: https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/