# Thread Safety with Spring and Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, thread-safety

I am curious on how thread safety plays into this scenario.

Say I have two class, validation classes, one inherits the other. The first is a simple java class, not managed by Spring, the second inherits the first and is a spring component.

```
public class FirstClass {
    private String[] supportedApps;

    public FirstClass(final String[] supportedApps){
        this.supportedApps = supportedApps;
    }

    private boolean isSupported(final String app){
        return .....;
    }
```

then we have a second class inheriting this, that is a Spring managed bean.

```
@Component
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass{

    @Autowired
    public SecondClass(@Value("${supported.apps} String[] supportedApps) {
         super(supportedApps)
         this.supportedApps = supportedApps;
     }

    other validations methods..  
}
```

Its also expected there will be a ThirdClass, also extending FirstClass with the same patter as SecondClass.

I am inclined to say this pattern is not thread safe. But, if the FirstClass is otherwise stateless. Can I expect the singleton creation of the SecondClass at context create to set the inheritance once? And that array, which is mutable, to not change?

UPDATE:

We do have static variables instantiated as immutableSets and static methods in FirstClass.

an operation in FirstClass may be:

```
public boolean isValidApp(final String app) {

    final List<String> apps = Arrays.asList(supportedApplications);
    return apps.contains(app);

}
```

Comment: *I am inclined to say this pattern is not thread safe.* - Why?

Comment: What do you mean by *to set the inheritance*?

Comment: They would be separate instances, and it doesn't appear their are any shared static class variables.  Why would they not be thread safe?

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about thread safety without knowing which operations two or more threads perform on shared resources.

Comment: As @lexicore alluded to, if you make your operations thread safe and use thread safe data structures, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are modifying both `SecondClass` and `ThirdClass` from multiple threads then they would not be thread-safe as they will be instantiated as singletons. What you can do is make your variables thread-safe. For example, if you are operating on an array or set, make those thread-safe.

If you do not modify fields of `SecondClass` and `ThirdClass` from multiple threads, I don't really see the problem. Keep in mind that it is not recommended to track state within the component.

Comment: These istances may or may not be thread safe depending on how operations executed by threads are implemented. Classes may very well provide thread-safe methods to work on shared state.

Comment: @LeBron James can you expand on the recommendation to not track state within the component?

Comment: @user3263752 having state in components makes it very error prone to multithreading problems and race conditions because the state is mutable. Take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803680/make-sure-spring-component-is-stateless